# How do I send HTML code in curl postfield and Process It

Tags: php, curl

For the past 48 hours have I been trying to pass an HTML code in an array and then past it to a curl posttfield... All answer I saw didn't solve it

```
$data = array(
    'to' => "$to",
    'message' => "$message",
    'subject' => "$subject",
    'replyTo' => "$replyTo",
    'senderName' => "$senderName"
    );   
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer $api"),
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,   
    CURLOPT_POSTREDIR => 3,   
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    ));
    $response =  curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
```

The "message" in the array is a HTML code, I have tried all the possible solution I saw online and none is working, Please help check If I am the one making mistakes
I tried doing this and then pass it to the array

```
$mes= http_build_query($message);
```

and still doesn't work..
also if passed, how do I process http_build_query data. Thanks

Edited: Using http_build_query send the message data but using $_POST("message") to process the data is empty

More Info
At the processing end, I have this line of code to receive the data

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    $api = getBearerToken(); 
    $to = xcape($conn, $_POST['to']); 
    
    
    $senderName = $_POST["senderName"]; 
  
    $message = $_POST["message"]; 
    
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

If I `echo $message;` I receive a blank space(i.e nothing comes up) but other work. I decided to do this `$mes= http_build_query($message);` and then replace the `$message` with `$mes` in the data array before sending and it is still showing blank

Comment: What exact problem are you running into? HTML is still just a string, so I don't see why it would cause any trouble.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can always skip the quotes on the variable in a situation such as `'senderName' => "$senderName"`

Comment: @El_Vanja, I don't know why it kept on showing blank on the other end of the API whenever I want to use it. Can you help with a sample code on receiving the data on the other end?

Comment: cURL does not care about what your data contains. On its own, it will not remove or change HTML markup to anything else

Comment: @NicoHaase Then what could I be doing wrong, because I create the API myself, receiving the data using $_POST($message) doesn't output anything

Comment: Whats the error you are getting

Comment: if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

Comment: `$_POST($message)`? Like that, literally? `$_POST` is an array, not a function. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Please share more details - "not working" is pretty broad, and as `$_POST` is an array, it's pretty obvious that it does not "output" anything. That's what you need to do with more code than you've provided so far

Comment: @El_Vanja error reporting is not showing anything. It is on

Comment: I can't reproduce. I send HTML to an endpoint and echo it back. I receive the same content.

Comment: @El_Vanja can I see a sample code? at the endpoint

Comment: I did the same things as you did. I just reduced it to `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { echo $_POST['message']; }`

Comment: @El_Vanja and your message are in HTML code? I mean it includes HTML tag?

Comment: Yes, I used a sample html: `<html><body><div>Message</div></body></html>`.

Comment: Maybe the issue has to do with my hosting provider because sending HTML tag in the array data return a 403 forbidden error including postman but removing the message will return 200 ok

Comment: Please share more details. Echo'ing markup might cause problems. What happens if you used `var_dump`?

Comment: Could it be my content type? var_dump doesn't show any output for message @NicoHaase